# How to state that belongs_to can't be null in a migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is it possible to state that a belongs_to type of field can't be null? Right now I have the following migration:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.belongs_to :site
      t.string :title

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The generates a table where `site_id` can be null.

Comment: You want to add a not null constraint to this field to the database?

Comment: @sam yes, exactly.

Comment: please check the answer below to see if it is something you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add options to `belongs_to`, so here you can add `null:false` option.

```rb
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.belongs_to :site, null: false
      t.string :title

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```